# Click on a dropdown box to get options list available

Tags: python, selenium

When I check a dropdown box using manual check, there is always a value offered.
When I use selenium to select the value, sometimes, there is offered options

```
select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath))
print(",".join( [o.text for o in select.options])
```

options is sometimes empty

as if the options could be filled when the user click on the dropdown box.
I tried all the following

```
wait = WebDriverWait (brower, 10)
optionValue = xpath + "/option[.='Value']"
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, optionValue)))
...
select.select_by_visible_text("Value")
...
select.select_by_index(1)
```

select does not have a click() method to open the menu.

What advices do you have ?

**Self answer -- Deep apologies**

In fact the dropdown is inside a popup, triggered by a button. When the popup is triggered too early, it never get filled after. Therefore I added a test which trigger the popup, check the content of the dropdown and if the dropdown does not contains the value, I quit, wait a bit and do it again

```
nbAttemps = 5
waitTime = 2
optionIsFound = False
while nbAttemps > 0:
    nbAttemps = nbAttemps - 1
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='No distribution']").click()

    selectXpath="//div/div/bla bla bla"

    select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(selectXpath))
    options = [o.text for o in select.options]
    optionIsFound = "Value" in options
    logger.debug("Options in select are " + ",".join( options))
    logger.debug("nbAttemps = %d" % nbAttemps )
    logger.debug("optionIsFound= %s, Value not in %s" % (optionIsFound,options))
    if not optionIsFound:
        # close the popup
        webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
        time.sleep(waitTime)
    else:
        select.select_by_visible_text("Value")
        nbAttemps = 0
```

Comment: You need to use explicit wait for your `select` element.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _as if the options could be filled when the user click on the dropdown box_? Updated the question with the exact _Manual Steps_ and the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1):

You can first click on the dropdown box using `click()` method and then can select the value from the dropdown.

And in case the dropdown shows the list on hovering on the dropdown then you can use Action class and then use `moveToElement(element)` to hover on the dropdown and then use the `click()` method to click on the desired value from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try Options

```
def objectoperation(objidtype, objid,texttofind):
element =  driver.find_element(objidtype, objid)
    for option in element.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text == texttofind:
            option.click()
            break
```

Let me know if it works.